# Starting an .exe from the same folder of my C# program

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a small program in c# with a button that is supposed to open another .exe file.

It works fine if I use:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"path to file");
        }
```

But not if I want it to run an .exe from the same folder, i basically wanted something like:

```
private void start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"program.exe");
        }
```

What am I missing, I've tried a solution from this website:

```
var startIngo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startIngo.WorkingDirectory = // working directory
// set additional properties 

Process proc = Process.Start(startIngo);
```

But Visual c# doesn't recognize "ProcessStartInfo" at all...

Comment: What do you mean C# dosen't Recognize `ProcessStartInfo` ? Sure it does.

Comment: By the way, in order for C# to recognize ProcessStartInfo, you need to import the System.Diagnostics namespace.

Answer (score 11):

What your looking for is:

```
Application.StartupPath
```

It will return the startup path that your executable was started in.

If you are using WPF, try this instead:

```
String appStartPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
```

Comment: Could you give me an example usage for this? I'm terribly new to this, and I don't quite understand the microsoft website explanation.

Comment: He's using WPF, not Windows Forms - this unfortunately won't work (it was my original thought as well).

Comment: @Reed: Just updated my answer to include a WPF solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
var startupPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
                       System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var programPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(startupPath, "program.exe");

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(programPath);
```

Comment: I get an error for StartupPath when I add this to my button event.

Comment: @Joao: I edited my answer to include the fully qualified name.  Does that correct it?

Comment: I get the error after pasting your code in my event:

The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Joao: I missed that you're using WPF - I've updated my answer to a WPF-compatible version.  This should give you what you need ;)

Answer (score 0):

`ProcessStartInfo` is in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace - you need to import that namespace at the top of your cs file using a `using System.Diagnostics;` statement for the compiler to recognise `ProcessStartInfo` without specifying the namespace explicitly where you use the class.

Comment: Alright, I've added "using System.Diagnostics;" to the top of my page, how would my code look for this to work though?

startIngo.WorkingDirectory = // working directory

Am I supposed to just insert the exe name after the = or something?

Comment: @Joao That should resolve the "But Visual c# doesn't recognize "ProcessStartInfo" at all.." though.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);`

To get your local path. For example

```
//in your imports/using section
using System.IO
using System.Reflection
using System.Diagnostics;

//in your code to execute
Process.start(Path.GetDirectoryName(Aseembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase) + "\\program.exe")
```

Comment: I put those 3 on my import and insert the rest of the code on my event, I get these errors:

Error 1 'System.Diagnostics.Process' does not contain a definition for 'start' 
Error 2 'Path' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Shapes.Path' and 'System.IO.Path'
Error 3 'System.Windows.Shapes.Path' does not contain a definition for 'GetDirectoryName' 
Error 4 The name 'Aseembly' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases:

1. The application was started directly - start up path can be extracted from the command-line.
2. The application was started indirectly - e.g. from a unit-test, start up path can not be extracted from the command-line, however you can read it from the current directory into a static variable during the start-up (before the user has a chance to change it (e.g. using a file open/save dialog)).